# Does anyone know how to draw a mouse with a rectangle in Blazor

Tags: javascript, blazor

I have a site written in Blazor that does text based image editing using a language I invented called Bitmap Query Language, or BQL for short.

Instead of typing a query like this:

Hide
Total < 200
X Between 200 640
Y Between 90 150

I would like the user to be able to select a rectangle with their mouse.

Is there a JavaScript way to draw a rectangle and get back the Top Left X, Y coordinates and the size of the rectangle relative to the div that is drawn?

I already have some JavaScript interop I use to get the size of a div:

```
public async static Task<System.Drawing.Rectangle> GetElementSize(IJSRuntime jsRuntime, string name)
{
    Rectangle rectangle;

    try
    {
        // get the height and width
        int height = await jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<int>("BlazorJSFunctions.GetElementHeight", name);
        int width = await jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<int>("BlazorJSFunctions.GetElementWidth", name);
          
        // set the size of the rectangle
        rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
    }
    catch (Exception error)
    {
        // for debugging only
        string err = error.ToString();
    }

    // Implemented in BlazorJSInterop.js
    return rectangle;
}
```

I had to make two calls was the only way I could figure out to get the div size to work. I know there is a way to do that in 1 step, but that is only slightly related to this question.

With this I would like to show a highlighted selection, kind of like Paint.Net:

[image]

And if I can get back the coordinates of the rectangle in C# land (outside of JavaScript) I could populate the text query box to 'Pixels In Selection' or something like that.

Here is my first and only JavaScript Interop scripts:

Just showing this in case it helps you tell me how to integrate your solution into my project.

```
window.BlazorJSFunctions =
{
    ShowPrompt: function (message)
    {
        return prompt(message, 'System Message');
    },
    GetElementHeight: function (name)
    {
        return document.getElementById(name).offsetHeight;
    },
    GetElementWidth: function (name)
    {
        return document.getElementById(name).offsetWidth;
    },
    CopyText: function (text)
    {
        // original value
        var returnValue = 0;

        try
        {
            navigator.clipboard.writeText(text);

            // set to 1;
            returnValue = 1;
        }
        catch (err)
        {
            returnValue = -2;
        }  

        // return value
        return returnValue;
    }
};
```

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

in most cases I use SVG, cause it is part of the dom. Can attach events and get mouseeventargs

Comment: I don't even know what SVG is. I will Google it and report back. Thanks.

Comment: SVG won't work for me, as I have to work with Pixels, which means bitmaps like .jpg or .png, thus the name of my site PixelDatabase.Net. Thanks anyway though.

Answer (score 1):

SVG is the correct approch.
Here is an example.
The rect class is filled by mouse events, used to display SVG rectangle and you can use it to do your image processing.

```
@page "/"
<img width="1200" height="900" 
     @onpointerdown=PointerDown 
     @onpointerdown:preventDefault
     @onpointerup=PointerUp @onpointerup:preventDefault
     @onpointermove=PointerMove @onpointermove:preventDefault 
     src="/mire.png"
     style="position:absolute;z-index:1;"
     />
@if (myRect.display)
{
    <svg width="1200" height="900" style="position: absolute; z-index: 2;" 
     @onpointerdown=PointerDown @onpointerdown:preventDefault
     @onpointerup=PointerUp @onpointerup:preventDefault
     @onpointermove=PointerMove @onpointermove:preventDefault 
     >
         <rect x="@myRect.x" y="@myRect.y" width="@myRect.width" height="@myRect.height" style="fill:transparent;stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(237, 255, 0)" />
     </svg>
 }
@code{
public class rect
{
    public bool display { get; set; }
    public double x { get; set; }
    public double y { get; set; }
    public double width { get; set; }
    public double height { get; set; }
}
rect myRect = new rect();
bool mouseDown = false;
Task PointerDown(PointerEventArgs e)
{
    mouseDown = true;
    myRect.display = true;
    myRect.x = e.ScreenX;
    myRect.y = e.ScreenY;
    myRect.width = 2;
    myRect.height = 2;
    StateHasChanged();
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}

Task PointerUp(PointerEventArgs e)
{
    mouseDown = false;
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}

Task PointerMove(PointerEventArgs e)
{
    if (mouseDown)
    {
        myRect.width = e.ScreenX - myRect.x;
        myRect.height = e.ScreenY - myRect.y;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
}
```

Comment: Does SVG work with a .png or .jpg? My site only accepts .png's or .jpgs to uploaded. Thanks

Comment: The principle here is to have two layers. The SVG area is transparent and place above what you want. In this example it's a <img>. When the rectangle is draw by the user, on PointerUp you have the final rectangle in myRect and can use this information to process the image.